# The 'suite-sdk debug' command failed. - Boundless SDK and OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, openlayers, sdk, debugging

I have a few questions about the creation of an application with
Boundless SDK and OpenLayers 3.

I'm trying to create an application with the templates ol3view and ol3edit, using the
command suite-sdk, according to your instructions:

- http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/07/build-apps-with-boundless-sdk/ and
- http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/webapps/ol3/templates.html.

But  the following error message comes up:
**« The 'suite-sdk debug' command failed. »**

Could you help me with this inconvenience?

I used:

> Operative System : Windows 7
>
> Java JDK 7u67

Also, I did the same test with «Centos 6.5», and also with the same error message.

I am detailing the steps taken at the end of this message.

---

## Step 1:  Create application « mivisor » with openlayers 3

```
C:\>suite-sdk create mivisor ol3view

Creating application ...

Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\build.xml

checkpath:

create:
Created dir: C:\mivisor
Copying 65 files to C:\mivisor
Created application: C:\mivisor

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

C:\>
```

## Step 2: Debug

```
C:\>suite-sdk debug c:/mivisor

Starting debug server for application (use CTRL+C to stop)

Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\build.xml

checkpath:

debug:

The 'suite-sdk debug' command failed.

Two commmon causes of this are:
* The directory provided did not contain a valid SDK application: "c:/mivisor"
* There was a conflict with the provided local port (-l): 9080

Please run 'suite-sdk debug --help' for help on the usage.

See the logfile 'C:\Users\pamor213\AppData\Local\Temp\suite-sdk\suite-sdk.log' f
or more detail on what went wrong.
```

I had the same error message with:

`C:\>suite-sdk debug -l 8000 c:/mivisor` , and

`C:\>suite-sdk debug -g http://localhost:8080/geoserver c:/mivisor`

## Step 3: looking at Log file

I go to logfile and I got the following message:

```
Checking provided application path.
Starting debug server for 'c:\mivisor.
Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.ringojs.tools.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:66)
    at org.ringojs.tools.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:383)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:335)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.reflect(JavaMembers.java:455)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.<init>(JavaMembers.java:76)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.lookupClass(JavaMembers.java:847)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.initMembers(NativeJavaClass.java:84)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.<init>(NativeJavaClass.java:78)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrapJavaClass(WrapFactory.java:167)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:165)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:114)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2081)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1524)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1510)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39._c_Server_1(ringo/httpserver.js:296)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39.call(ringo/httpserver.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:369)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2440)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39._c_init_21(ringo/httpserver.js:425)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39.call(ringo/httpserver.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39._c_main_25(ringo/httpserver.js:495)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.ringo_httpserver_js_39.call(ringo/httpserver.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C__Program_Files__x86__Boundless_OpenGeo_sdk_src_main_resources_server_main_js_3._c_script_0(C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\src\main\resources\server\main.js:31)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C__Program_Files__x86__Boundless_OpenGeo_sdk_src_main_resources_server_main_js_3.call(C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\src\main\resources\server\main.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:426)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3178)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C__Program_Files__x86__Boundless_OpenGeo_sdk_src_main_resources_server_main_js_3.call(C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\src\main\resources\server\main.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C__Program_Files__x86__Boundless_OpenGeo_sdk_src_main_resources_server_main_js_3.exec(C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\src\main\resources\server\main.js)
    at org.ringojs.engine.ReloadableScript.evaluate(ReloadableScript.java:196)
    at org.ringojs.engine.RhinoEngine.evaluateScript(RhinoEngine.java:510)
    at org.ringojs.engine.RhinoEngine.runScript(RhinoEngine.java:188)
    at org.ringojs.tools.RingoRunner.run(RingoRunner.java:151)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\sdk\build.xml:88: Java returned: 2

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/issues/612 and see if putting in that extra jar file resolves it for you as well.